# Visual Studio 2013 Set as start up project does not change the project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have several projects in the solution. When I set the "Set as start up project" (In VS 2013) to the Console application project and when I hit F5, it sets the start up project to a particular class library project (Class Library 1). I cannot change the start up project from "Class Library 1" to anything else. I tried to change the start up project by right clicking the project as well as right clicking the solution and then set the start up project from there.

When I set the start up project as the "Console App1" project, it indicates that it has been selected properly (bold the project name). But once I hit F5, it tries to execute "Class Library 1" (bold the Class Library project) and gives an error (A project with Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly).

I tried to delete the .suo file and open up the solution, still I am getting the issue. 
Where is the start up project details are stored? Could not find any clue inside the sln file as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. Forgot to mention that I am using Resharper. There was a resharper "dotSettings" file (.sln.DotSettings.user) in the solution directory which has the following entry,

```
<s:String
x:Key="/Default/RunConfigs/Config/=9DF93B60D662E841A397F5FDE870C414/Name/@EntryValue">Class Library 1</s:String>
```

Solution is to delete this file. (Changing this entry did not solve the issue.)

Comment: Same issue occurred with VS2015, and deleting the DotSettings.user fixed it as well.

Comment: worked for me as well, but I just changed the name of the project and the project-guid which is defined below.